# invalidateViews() and notifyDataSetChanged() doesnt work for me

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i using ListView in fragment. I have one asynctask to download json data from remote server. I try refresh programmatically my displayed adapter/listview in onPostExecute function but it doesn't work for me.

My main activity with three fragments, three listview, three adapter and one async task.

```
public class ContactsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static List<Item> BackList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static List<Item> BackList2 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static List<Item> BackList3 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static ListView ListView;
    private static Context activity;
    public static String HASH;
    private static final String[] timestamp = {"0"};
    private static WeatherAdapter adapter;
    private static int fragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

        Intent myIntent= getIntent();
        HASH = myIntent.getStringExtra("HASH");
        Log.d("Intent - contactActivity", HASH);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
        (new PrefetchData()).execute();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            fragment = position;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            int index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            fragment = index;

            activity = getActivity();
            ListView listview1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            switch(fragment){
                case 1:
                    adapter = new WeatherAdapter(activity,  R.layout.listview_item_row, BackList);
                    listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            Intent rozmowa = new Intent(getActivity(), Incotalk.class);
                            rozmowa.putExtra("HASH", HASH);
                            startActivity(rozmowa);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 2:
                    adapter = new WeatherAdapter(activity,  R.layout.listview_item_row2, BackList2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    adapter = new WeatherAdapter(activity,  R.layout.listview_item_row3, BackList3);
                    break;
            }

            listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
            ListView = listview1;


            return rootView;
        }
    }



    /**
     * Async Task to make http call
     */
    private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // before making http calls
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            final String id = HASH;
            final String url = "http://freshfrog.pl/projects/talk.php?user="+id+"&t=" +  timestamp[0];
            Log.d("BBB","start");

                try {
                    String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(url);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
                    timestamp[0] = jsonObject.getString("t");


                    HASH = jsonObject.getJSONObject("s").getString("hash");
                    JSONArray oczekujacy = jsonObject.getJSONArray("m");


                    // wiadomosci
                    BackList.clear(); // czyści przed odświerzeniem
                    BackList2.clear();
                    BackList3.clear();


                    for (int i=oczekujacy.length()-1; i>0; i--) {
                        JSONObject actor = oczekujacy.getJSONObject(i);
                        String message = actor.getString("m");
                        String hash = actor.getString("n");
                        String t = actor.getString("t");

                        int l = BackList.size();
                        Boolean jest = false;

                        for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
                            Item item = BackList.get(j);
                            if(!item.isSection()){
                                ContactItem contactItem= (ContactItem) item;
                                if(  (contactItem.hash).equals(hash)  ){
                                    jest = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            //Log.d("bbb", BackList.get(j).hash);
                        }

                        if(!jest && !hash.equals(id))    BackList.add(
                                new ContactItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                                        message,
                                        hash));
                    }

                    // znajomi
                    BackList2.add(new SectionItem("Otrzymane zaproszenia"));
                    oczekujacy = jsonObject.getJSONObject("f").getJSONObject("p").getJSONArray("sending");
                    for (int i=0; i<oczekujacy.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject actor = oczekujacy.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = actor.getString("name");
                        String hash = actor.getString("hash");
                        String avatar = actor.getString("avatar");

                        BackList2.add(new ContactItem(getBitmapFromURL(avatar) , name, hash)   );
                    }



                    // szukaj
                    BackList3.add(new SectionItem("Znajomi"));
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext())
                    {

                        String name=    phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        BackList3.add(new ContactItem(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                                name,
                                phoneNumber)   );
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("BBB", e.toString());
                }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /* gdy skończy */

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listview2.invalidateViews();

            //Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, "coś przyszło", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("BBB", "powinno sie odswieżyc");
            new PrefetchData().execute();
        }

    }

}
```

My custom adapter

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Item> data = null;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;
        SectionHolder holder2 = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        Item i = data.get(position);
        if(row == null){
            if(!i.isSection()){
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new WeatherHolder();
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                row.setTag(holder);

                ContactItem contactItem = (ContactItem)i;
                holder.txtTitle.setText(contactItem.title);
                holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(contactItem.icon);
            }else{

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, parent, false);
                holder2 = new SectionHolder();
                holder2.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                row.setTag(holder2);

                SectionItem sectionItem = (SectionItem)i;
                holder2.txtTitle.setText(sectionItem.title);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if(!i.isSection()){
                //holder = (WeatherHolder)    row.getTag();
            }else{
                //holder2 = (SectionHolder)   row.getTag();
            }

        }


        return row;
    }

    public void update(List<Item> newlist) {
        Log.d("bbb","aktualizacja listview");
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(newlist);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() // Create this function in your adapter class
    {
        //notifySetDataChanged()
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
    static class SectionHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you overriding notifyDataSetChanged???

Comment: i want to check this function call properly and before i added Log.d with communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the part of the "if(row == null){" should only contain initializations of the views and the viewHolders.

it shouldn't contain any setting of data to the views.

after this part ( after the "else {...}" ) , you should update the views with the new data .

here's my fix to your code (looks ugly, but should work) :

```
    ...
    int type=getViewType();
    switch(type)
      {
      case 0:
        if(row == null)
          {
          row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
          holder = new WeatherHolder();
          holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
          holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
          row.setTag(holder);
          }
        else 
          holder = (WeatherHolder)    row.getTag();
        ContactItem contactItem = (ContactItem)i;
        holder.txtTitle.setText(contactItem.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(contactItem.icon);   
        break;
      case 1:
        if(row == null)
          {
          row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, parent, false);
          holder2 = new SectionHolder();
          holder2.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
          row.setTag(holder2);
          }
        else 
          holder2 = (SectionHolder)   row.getTag();
        SectionItem sectionItem = (SectionItem)i;
        holder2.txtTitle.setText(sectionItem.title); 
        break;
     }
    return row;
...

... int getViewType(...) {... return i.isSection()? 1:0;}

... int getViewTypeCount(){return 2;}
```

btw, you should really watch the lecture "[**the world of listView**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" . they have great tips that will make your code much better.

for example, you can use getViewTypeCount , getViewType, getItem, as shown on [**the API**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) .

Comment: I work for my. But when i use Section i have error " java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.WeatherAdapter$WeatherHolder cannot be cast to com.xxx.WeatherAdapter$SectionHolder"

i look like function isSection() doesnt work properly here if(!i.isSection()) holder = (WeatherHolder)    row.getTag();  else     holder2 = (SectionHolder)   row.getTag();

Comment: well that's a different reason and i just copied your code, assuming you know what you are doing . since views are recycled, and you didn't use getViewType, all views should have the same ViewHolder (since all are of the same type). please just watch the lecture. i think it will help you a lot.

Comment: anyway, i've now updated the code. i didn't test it, but in general it should work now that it has multiple view types, instead of just one as you've done.

Comment: @EliaszKubala i still think you should watch the video. in any case, if you think this answers your question, please tick the answer with a "V" and/or upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

to view your code i see that you have started your async execution again on postExcecute

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /* gdy skończy */

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listview2.invalidateViews();

            //Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, "coś przyszło", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("BBB", "powinno sie odswieżyc");
            new PrefetchData().execute();
        }
```

also clearing data inside your doBackground

To get changes on your data you should not clear your data just get updates records and notify your adapeter

Comment: I try do something like longpooling in Java Script. When i should clear adapter?

Answer (score -1):

try to change the method data.addAll(newlist) by using addall(newlist, data);
inside addall method add one by one the list of element. this way it should work.

i had the same problem and i correct it the way i explained.